# Merge [tag:uk] and [tag:united-kingdom]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There is a frequently used tag [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk).  I think this would be better called [united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom), considering that for other countries, we also use the full name rather than a two-letter abbreviation.  [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) can then be a synonym.

Comment: I just attempted to do a merge, but there was a problem with SE's servers.  I'll see if the issue clears up tomorrow and try again

Comment: @SamIam Could you try again?  They don't seem to be merged.

Comment: @SamIam Maybe try again now? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be marked status completed now, as those two tags are merged.