# Use [united-kingdom] instead of [uk]?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk), [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), [united-nations](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-nations) and [european-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union) as the master tags. All of these are non-abbreviated, except for [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk).

Shouldn't [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) be a synonym of [united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) instead of the other way round?

---

**Note:** This question is related to [Merge [tag:uk] and [tag:united-kingdom]](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/merge-taguk-and-tagunited-kingdom), however it is not a duplicate as this question is asking to reverse the tag synonym while the other question is requesting for a tag merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) should now be the master tag